# What do you call someone who desperately needs (or better said craves) everyone to like them?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I have this friend who is in constant search for approval - and not only from his peers, but every single person he meets. He also needs to be the center of attention.

Comment: Psychologically speaking: insecure.

Answer (score 10):

I think the most obvious choice would be *needy* itself:

> **needy** *adj*
>   2. Wanting or needing affection, attention, or reassurance, especially to an excessive degree.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/needy)

Note that in AmE you will frequently hear the term "high maintenance" ("My girlfriend/boyfriend is so high maintenance!") used as a synonym for *needy*. Whereas *needy* has an alternate meaning that refers to someone who is merely poor or disadvantaged, *high maintenance* has nothing associated with it that absolves its target from blame.

Comment: Yep, "needy" is definitely used in the US, among younger and especially female folks.  As is "high maintenance".  Another related term is "drama queen", for someone who always has a crisis which is more important than anyone else's concerns.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more pejorative term, in the US, you would call him an

> attention whore

a more polite version of this is

> attention hog

If they tend to seek approval by trying to please everyone, then you could use

> **sycophant**
>
> noun
>
> a person who acts obsequiously toward someone important in order to gain advantage.  (Google)

or its synonyms:

> yes-man, bootlicker, brown-noser, toady, lickspittle, flatterer, flunky, lackey, spaniel, doormat, stooge, cringer, suck, suck-up  (Google)

Answer (score 1):

Your friend wants to be a **cynosure**.

TFD defines *cynosure* as *a person or thing that attracts notice, esp because of its brilliance or beauty*.

Your friend may or may not attract every person, but he definitely strives to be one.